# How to use combobox value to vlookup value for another text value in a userform and have it update automatically in the userform

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, vlookup, userform

I'm not seeing what is not working on this one.

I want after the user selects SelectAgency a userform combobox for the Contact1 populate from reference sheet with a named range in column T

```
column s on ref sheet = Agency name 
column t on ref sheet = Contact1. name
ACIN = column t range for contacts
```

I've been trying a few ways - vlookup method, offset method, and started on the find method. I've seen a few questions kind of close, but not quite what I needed.  Any help would be Great! :)  Thanks!

```
Private Sub SelectAgency_Afterupdate()

 'Me.Contact1.Value = Application.VLookup(SelectAgency.Value, Worksheets("Ref   Sheet - Delimited list").Range("AC1N"), 1, 0)

'Me.Contact1.Value = Worksheets("Ref Sheet - Delimited list").Range(SelectAgency.Value).Offset(0, 1)



'Dim ws5 As Worksheet
'Dim lRow2
'Me.Contact1.Value = lRow2 = ws5.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
'  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

End Sub
```

Comment: Does it have to be a combobox? You can create a more vlookup-friendly drop down box using Data Validation without any code.

Comment: unfortunately yes, but good news    found the solution  Me.Contact1.Value = Application.VLookup(SelectAgency.Value, Worksheets("Ref Sheet - Delimited list").Range("S2:T300"), 2, 0)  for whatever reason it doesn't like doing a vlookup on first column so I expanded it.. seemed to work :)

Comment: You can post the answer to your own question, below, for others

Answer (score 0):

Me.Contact1.Value = Application.VLookup(SelectAgency.Value, Worksheets("Ref Sheet - Delimited list").Range("S2:T300"), 2, 0)

expanded selection picked second column and didn't use the named range ACIN used the cell ranges.